# display list of buffers `ls` without scrolling down

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, buffers

Is there a way to display output at the bottom of the screen like `ls` does, but without *scrolling down to accomodate the output*?

The [Vim Wiki (no https)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cycle_through_buffers_including_hidden_buffers) has the following snippet

```
:nnoremap <A-n> :bnext<CR>:redraw<CR>:ls<CR>
:nnoremap <A-p> :bprevious<CR>:redraw<CR>:ls<CR>
```

I've tried binding this as

```
nnoremap <silent> <tab>   :bnext<cr>:redraw<cr>:ls<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <S-tab> :bprevious<cr>:redraw<cr>:ls<cr>
```

however, when moving to the next buffer and displaying `ls`, vim truncates the top `n` lines of the buffer, with `n` being the number of lines needed to display `ls`.

For instance, if I have the following file `b.tex` with line numbers:

```
  1 \documentclass{article}
  2
  3 \begin{document}
  4
  5 Lorem ipsem
  6
  7 $$ \frac{a}{b} $$
  8
  9 \end{document}
```

And the files `a.tex b.tex c.tex` open, then pressing `tab` and navigating to  `b.tex` produces the following output

```
      5 Lorem ipsem
      6
      7 $$ \frac{a}{b} $$
      8
      9 \end{document}
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"./tmp/b.tex" 9 lines --11%-- ((1) of 3)
  1 #h   "./tmp/a.tex"      line 1
  2 %a   "./tmp/b.tex"      line 1
  3  h   "./tmp/c.tex"      line 1
```

Is there a way to direct vim to *take the four lines needed to display the output of `ls` from the bottom of the buffer rather than the top*?

Comment: I doubt it, but im interested to see folks try

Comment: Not generally possible, but you could temporarily increase the `cmdheight` option value

Comment: There are some "Buffer Explorer" that might give you a different look&feel. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148887/buffer-explorer-for-vim) or google.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt so I assume there's no configurable setting that would make Vim behave this way for all commands? I'd be interested in trying to implement this change for Vim, would you happen to know roughly where this logic is defined?

Comment: @henrebotha have a look at `msg_outtrans()` in message.c